# My AJAX call only returns partial of my database and won't load more on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've made an AJAX script which loads data from my database on scroll. I have 24 records in my database, but when I scroll down it only seems to load 20 of them and stops there, instead of loading the remainder of the 4 records.

I've tried playing around with the offset and limit I've set on loading the records, but I can't seem to get it right. When I resize my browser, it does seem to load everything which is odd.

My HTML are just 2 basic div's

```
<div class="articles">

        </div>
    <div class="articlesFade">

    </div>
```

And my JavaScript is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var increaseArticles = 0;
//get the first 10 articles from the database query in database.php
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "php/database.php",
        data: {
            'offset': 0,
            'limit': 10
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('.articles').append(data);
            increaseArticles += 10;
        }
    });

//scroll down to load the next batch of 10
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "php/database.php",
                data: {
                    'offset': increaseArticles,
                    'limit': 10
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('.articlesFade').append(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
                    increaseArticles += 10;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I think the problem might the scrollTop call, but I've not found any other way of achieving a "lazyloader" effect. I want to program it myself, that's why I haven't used a plugin. Hopefully it's not some small rookie mistake, because I've spent way too much time on this little thing already

Comment: try setting cache to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scroll` event is firing something like 10-15 times in a single small wheel action.

So it fires just too often to have an async Ajax request in between each of these event.

Result is `increaseArticles` gets increased to fast by concurring requests.

So try using a "flag" to limit those requests...

See comments in code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var increaseArticles = 0;
  //get the first 10 articles from the database query in database.php
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/database.php",
    data: {
      'offset': 0,
      'limit': 10
    },
    success: function(data){
      $('.articles').append(data);
      increaseArticles += 10;
    }
  });

  // Flag
  var ajaxRunning=false;
  var allResultsReceived=false;
      
  //scroll down to load the next batch of 10
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        
      // If there is no Ajax request pending
      if(!ajaxRunning && !allResultsReceived){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "php/database.php",
          data: {
            'offset': increaseArticles,
            'limit': 10
          },
          success: function(data){
            $('.articlesFade').append(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
            increaseArticles += 10;
            
            var howManyResult = (data.match(/.column/g) || []).length;
            
            if(howManyResult!=10){
              allResultsReceived=true;    // Disable all future request call.
            }
            
            // Reset flag;
            ajaxRunning=false;
          }
        });
      
        // Set flag to true to prevent concurring ajax resquest.
        ajaxRunning=true;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This optimises the code, but yet, the issue that I only get my records by 10 remains. It still doesn't load the remaining 4 records in my database.

Comment: Try to `console.log(increaseArticles)` at the beginning of the `scroll` handler... To at least see if this is the problem. If this value is ok, I would check on PHP side.

Comment: console.log(increaseArticles) returns nothing in the console, not at the beginning of the scroll handler, but also not at the end. Is that the issue?

Comment: Strange... Do you have a live link to this page ?

Comment: http://rickyrekkers.nl/Papery/index.php is the live version, I just tried adding a -100 to the window scrollTop call, that loads the articles for a moment, but bugs out and unloads them.

Comment: I see 24 posts. What I would do now, is in the `success` callback, check if the response is less than 10 results to set a flag which will prevent future request for good. Since there is no more results in DB... Better shut the calls there! It will remove the useless fadein effect on each scroll.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip! On my screen it somehow only loads 20 posts, which might be a screen bug, instead of a major mistake.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and retry... You are supposed to see 24 post too. There is no "screen bug" possible.

Comment: My website is responsive and somehow on my resolution there's only 20 records. If I however resize my browser and scroll down more show up and it works. Also on higher resolutions you can't scroll, so the script is absolute, I guess I need to fix the amount of records on screensize

Comment: @marc_s This "collumn" with two "l" came from the OP website's code. Please, leave it as is. This is a `class` name... It can be anything.